# Custom control inside repeat can't see rowData in one custom property, but work in other

Tags: xpages, custom-controls, xpages-ssjs

I have following custom control:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:compositeData.id = this.getId();
if (!compositeData.body_class) {compositeData.body_class='panel-body'};
if (!compositeData.panel_id) {compositeData.panel_id='section'+compositeData.id};}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>
    <xp:panel>
        <xp:this.styleClass><![CDATA[#{javascript:"ccSectionPanel panel " + compositeData.panel_class + ""}]]></xp:this.styleClass>
            <xp:this.attrs>
                <xp:attr name="id">
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:compositeData.panel_id}]]></xp:this.value>
                </xp:attr>
            </xp:this.attrs>
        <xp:panel styleClass="panel-heading" style="cursor:pointer;">
            <xp:this.attrs>
                <xp:attr name="id">
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:compositeData.panel_id + "_heading"}]]></xp:this.value>
                </xp:attr>
                <xp:attr name="href">
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:"#" + compositeData.panel_id + "_section"}]]></xp:this.value>
                </xp:attr>
                <xp:attr name="data-toggle" value="collapse"></xp:attr>
            </xp:this.attrs>


            <xp:link escape="true" styleClass="panel-title"
                text="#{javascript:compositeData.titleBarText}">
                <xp:this.attrs>
                    <xp:attr name="id">
                        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:compositeData.panel_id + "_title"}]]></xp:this.value>
                    </xp:attr>
                </xp:this.attrs>
                <xp:this.id><![CDATA[${javascript:compositeData.panel_id + "_title"}]]></xp:this.id>
            </xp:link>
        </xp:panel>

        <xp:panel>
            <xp:this.styleClass><![CDATA[#{javascript:"panel-collapse collapse" + (compositeData.initClosed ? "" : " in")}]]></xp:this.styleClass>
            <xp:this.attrs>
                <xp:attr name="id">
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:compositeData.panel_id + "_section"}]]></xp:this.value>
                </xp:attr>
            </xp:this.attrs>
            <xp:panel
                styleClass="#{javascript:compositeData.body_class}">
                <xp:callback facetName="panelBody" id="panelBody"></xp:callback>
            </xp:panel>
            <xp:panel rendered="#{javascript:compositeData.footer}"
                styleClass="panel-footer">
                <xp:callback facetName="panelFooter" id="panelFooter"></xp:callback>
            </xp:panel>
        </xp:panel>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

I use it in a repeat control:

```
<xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30" value="#{view1}"
                    var="repEntry" indexVar="index" repeatControls="false">
                    <xp:panel>
                        <xp:this.data>
                            <xp:dominoDocument var="doc"
                                action="openDocument"
                                documentId="#{javascript:repEntry.getNoteID()}"
                                ignoreRequestParams="true">
                            </xp:dominoDocument>
                        </xp:this.data>
                        <xc:ccSectionPanel initClosed="false"
                            panel_class="#{javascript:repEntry.getColumnValue('class')}"
                            footer="#{javascript:sessionScope.isAdmin}"
                            rendered="#{javascript:repEntry.getColumnValue('Status') == '1' || sessionScope.isAdmin}">
                            <xc:this.titleBarText><![CDATA[#{javascript:repEntry.getColumnValue('Title') + (repEntry.getColumnValue('Status') != '1' ? ' (скрыто)' : '')

}]]></xc:this.titleBarText>
                            <xp:this.facets>
                                <xp:panel xp:key="panelFooter">

                                    <xp:button value="Редактировать"
                                        id="button2" styleClass="btn btn-xs">
                                        <i
                                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil">
                                        </i>
                                        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick"
                                            submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
                                            <xp:this.action>
                                                <xp:openPage
                                                    name="/index.xsp" target="editDocument"
                                                    documentId="#{javascript:repEntry.getNoteID()}">
                                                </xp:openPage>
                                            </xp:this.action>
                                        </xp:eventHandler>
                                    </xp:button>
                                    <xp:button
                                        value="#{javascript:repEntry.getColumnValue('Status') != '1' ? 'Показать' : 'Скрыть'}"
                                        id="button3" styleClass="#{javascript:'btn btn-xs'}">
                                        <i
                                            class="#{javascript:repEntry.getColumnValue('Status') != '1' ? 'glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open' : 'glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close'}">
                                        </i>
                                        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick"
                                            submit="true" refreshMode="partial" disableValidators="true"
                                            refreshId="content">
                                            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:if (repEntry.getColumnValue('Status') == '1') {
    doc.replaceItemValue('Status','0');
    doc.replaceItemValue('Author',sessionScope.User.UserName);
    doc.save();
} else {
    doc.replaceItemValue('Status','1');
    doc.replaceItemValue('Author',sessionScope.User.UserName);
    doc.save();
}}]]></xp:this.action>
                                        </xp:eventHandler>
                                    </xp:button>
                                    <xp:text escape="false"
                                        id="computedField2" styleClass="btn btn-xs">
                                        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:'<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>' + repEntry.getColumnValue('Author') + '  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i>' + repEntry.getColumnValue('$1')
}]]></xp:this.value>
                                    </xp:text>
                                </xp:panel>
                                <xp:panel xp:key="panelBody">
                                    <!-- <xp:this.data>
                                        <xp:dominoDocument var="doc" action="openDocument"
                                        documentId="#{javascript:repEntry.getNoteID()}" 
                                        ignoreRequestParams="true">
                                        </xp:dominoDocument>
                                        </xp:this.data> -->
                                    <xp:inputRichText
                                        id="inputRichText2" value="#{doc.Body}" readonly="true"
                                        rendered="false">
                                    </xp:inputRichText>
                                    <xp:text escape="false"
                                        id="computedField1">
                                        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:doc.getDocument().getFirstItem("Body").getMIMEEntity().getContentAsText(); }]]></xp:this.value>
                                    </xp:text>


                                </xp:panel>
                            </xp:this.facets>
                        </xc:ccSectionPanel>
                    </xp:panel>
                </xp:repeat>
```

When i set cumputed properties, 
[image: (picture)]
It works, but when i set panel_id to something relative to repEntry or doc, it throws error (repEntry is undefined). I can set "Create controls at page creation", but then I lose advantages of partial refresh.

The main question, why one costom property can work with repEntry, but other can't?

Comment: What property type is "panel_id"? Which value did you set to property "panel_id"?

Comment: string and string. The question is why it cannot use row variable, but other one can.

Comment: I tried to set values:
1. repEntry.getPosition('.');
2. repEntry.getUniversalID();
3. doc.getNoteId();
doc is undefined, repEntry is undefined

Answer (score 0):

The answer comes down to when the property gets calculated. Compute it and add a print statement in the SSJS code and you'll see. IDs need to be calculated when the components get loaded, so at the earliest part of the processing. And most importantly this is when it's generating a single abstract set of components, not associated to a particular row entry, because it's not yet built the collection. Think of it like creating an abstract class before creating objects from it.

Comment: It will if you're trying to print out something relative to the repeat. If I can't debug and I want to display order of processing, I use something like `print("Computing ID");` Then in the repeat add something like `print("Loading repeat values");`. That would show order of processing and whether it's trying to compute IDs before it's iterated the values. You'll see it covered in more detail in this TLCC webinar I delivered https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t7j_MR5uzCA&feature=youtu.be.